# Handler.postDelayed v/s Runnable.run. Is it alright to call .run instead of .postDelayed?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable, android-handler

I was trying to implement a looping `Runnable`. The example I've found seems to use the following idea to kick-start the runnable.

```
        handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
                doIt();
                count ++;
            }
        };
        r.run();// what I prefer
//      handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);//their idea
```

I prefer using the call to the `run()` method to start the `Runnable`. What would be the possible troubles that I could get into if any by a direct call to `run()`!

Thanks! :)

Comment: Do you want it to run *now*, or in 1000 milliseconds?

Comment: What is the problem with handlers? Why you don't like them, they solve quite some problems you will be hitting with run.

Comment: @immibis I wasn't sure if postDelayed would do something more than just post it delayed into the queue. Looks like nothing else.

Comment: @BojanKseneman Just uncomfortable that's all. Could you elaborate a little more please? :)

Comment: Well runnable on it's own it's pretty dumb. You get to see it's lack of functionallity when you are trying to notify it about something, interrupt it, cancel it, pass it some data from another thread. Handler has these cases handled for you if you know how to properly use it. I advise you get to know more about it and you might start to like it and avoid runnables. The most important thing is that it's thread safe and it allows communication between threads!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I prefer using the call to the run() method to start the Runnable.

OK.

> What would be the possible troubles that I could get into if any by a direct call to run()!

The first pass through `run()` would happen immediately, as opposed to your commented-out code, which would cause the first pass through `run()` to occur ~1000ms from now.

However, I would dump the `Handler`. `postDelayed()` is also a method on `View`, so just use some widget in your UI.

Comment: Thank you!.. :) Also, this code is part of a service. So, I have to use a handler and can't use a UI widget. Right?..

Comment: @Harsh: If this is part of a service, you should be using `ScheduledExecutorService`, or perhaps `TimerTask`, from standard Java. You specifically want the service to be getting control periodically on a background thread, and those give you that.

Answer (score 3):

If you call `r.run()`, the `Runnable` will be executed immediately. But if you call `handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);` as they recommended, the `Runnable` will not be executed until 1s is past. So, this is the first point. Second, why don't you use the `Thread Loop merchanism` provided by `Android`, namely `Handler` `AsyncTask` `HandlerThread` for the sake that `Android` supports it very well?

Comment: Thank you! Also sorry, can't up-vote! Yeah, I have to yet research a little more about different Thread mechanisms. Never really had to use them much until now. Do you happen to know a resource where I can get a head-start on these?

Comment: @Harsh I think Multi-Thread of  https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html of android doc is a good start.